# Exiting from CockroachDB SQL CLI

Tags: cockroachdb

Once I’m in the CockroachDB SQL shell, how do I get out of it? I tried `exit;` and `quit;` and it didn’t work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can exit from the CockroachDB SQL CLI with `ctrl + C` or `\q`.

Answer (score 0):

you can also exit the CLI with `quit` or `exit` WITHOUT the training semicolon